# Using Both GraphQL and REST endpoints in Angular 9 Project

Tags: angular, graphql

My company develops webapps calling Microservices in REST. My team wants to start with our first GraphQL Services.

Would it be a bad practise to develop a few new services and call them inside our existing Angular 9 app which includes many REST endpoints? (We will be using both, REST and GraphQL in our projects)

PD: I ask this because I have seen the "GraphQL Gateway pattern" as a solution in most of similar use cases, I wanted to know your opinions and if it makes sense to use both REST and GraphQL in a first stage.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really good to know you are starting with GraphQl.

before heading with the answer, we also went through such a situation in our organization. we had similar microservice architecture and we created a new graphql service for few features and related usecase.

as we know REST is an architecture style for an API, which enables us to follow good practice.

Graphql on other hand is a data fetching language that allows clients to declaratively describe their data requirements in a JSON-like format. Furthermore, GraphQL is database agnostic. Its design allows you to deal with every kind of database.

the main things to get in our mind is GraphQL solves many problems, but not all.
which you might already know.

in our use case, we used graphql to get data on different web and phone applications accordingly in one endpoint. we wanted to show a few data points in the web app while we wanted to show different on the phone app. we also continued to use few REST endpoint which had a higher security level.

it is totally fine if you used both in-app. There won't be any issues handling your angular application. make a common service file in angular which handles graphql request and response.

I also came across a few demonstrations of graphql and rest where companies using both, for example when you are mutating data through GraphQL, the resolver redirects your request to the REST controller. If you had added policies, authentication's or validation rules on this controller's action, they will be resolved.